# Arrange columns of file

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed

First time I have encountered this kind of situation, and I can't be able to imagine the solution. I have a file that has multiple data columns, and they have arranged vertically one after another, with space in between. I want to make those columns one by one horizontally.

Files having:

```
123
456
789

789
456
123

456
123
789
```

File I am looking for:

```
123 789 456
456 456 123
789 123 789
```

Comment: What file type is it?

Comment: @Oxin It is a simple text file.

Comment: `pr -t3s' ' file.txt`

Comment: @Jetchisel Thank you for providing a solution. It works well for the example here. My real file has multiple columns, and each column has multiple elements. Could you bit tell me about the ````-t3s````? I think that helps me to find the solution.

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please describe the actual problem you need solved, not a problem you think will get you to where you can do it yourself.

Comment: please update the question to show a sample input file that *`has multiple columns, and each column has multiple elements`*

Comment: Using the same 3 values in each block makes it harder to understand your problem as we then have to guess where in the input each output value is coming from, and makes it harder to test with since a solution that prints the values in the wrong order could coincidentally produce the expected output. Use different values in each row across all blocks so it's unambiguous where each output value came from.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it in AWK:

```bash
$ awk -v RS= -v FS=\\n '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) a[i]=a[i] (a[i] ? " " : "") $i} END{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) print a[i]}' input.txt
123 789 456
456 456 123
789 123 789
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution. It arranges the columns but changes the order of each element. I got the following output.

    456 456 123
    789 123 789
    123 789 456

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby:

```
ruby -e '$<.read.
            split(/\R\R/).
            map(&:split).
            transpose.each{|row| puts row.join("\t")}
' file
```

In Python:

```
python3 -c 'import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    sa=[b.split("\n") for b in f.read().split("\n\n")]
print("\n".join(["\t".join(t) for t in zip(*sa)]))' file'
```

Or if you want Python to use stdin vs open the file:

```
python3 -c 'import sys
sa=[b.split("\n") for b in sys.stdin.read().split("\n\n")]
print("\n".join(["\t".join(t) for t in zip(*sa)]))' <file
```

If you have the [rs](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rs) utility installed (default on BSD, MacOS, several others...)

```
sed '/^$/d' file | paste - - - | rs -c -C -T
```

Any of those, with your example, prints:

```
123 789 456 
456 456 123 
789 123 789
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input file is fairly small (up to around 100 thousand lines should be OK) then a pure Bash solution is practical.  Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

rows=() r=0
while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    [[ -z $line ]] && r=0 || rows[r++]+=" $line"
done <input.txt
printf '%s\n' "${rows[@]# }"
```

- See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for an explanation of the `while read -r line ...` line.
- `"${rows[@]# }"` expands to the list of elements of the `rows` array with a space character removed from the start of each of them.  The code that adds values to rows adds an extra space at the start of every row.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;$s/$/\n/;/\n\+$/!ba;s/\n\+$//;y/\n/ /' file
```

Append the next line.

If it is the last line, append a newline.

If the last line(s) are not empty, repeat as above.

Otherwise, remove the empty line(s), replace any other newlines by spaces and print the result.

N.B. This caters both for the last line being empty or not.